# Customized view based on attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use **MVC5** to generate a table View for a Product Model.

I know that an attribute in the form of  [attribute] can be defined for an **Action** in the controller. But suppose that in my **Index** view I want to show all fields of the "**Product**" model to the admin (e.g. name, price, quantity), and only some fields of it, (e.g. only name and price) to the customers.

How can I edit my

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Products.ToList());
        }
```

to achieve this?

UPDATE: My question is whether I need to create multiple views or I have to somehow customize the view inside the Index() Action?

Comment: You have to use the `[Magic(Reason="Lazy")]` attribute.

Comment: Look at roles in MVC, as @JohnSaunders mentioned in his comment , there's (fortunately) no magical thing that will do that for you in one line of code

Comment: Well, of course. I didn't ask for one particular attribute as the answer. What would be the best practice to achieve this? creating multiple views? Putting authentication inside the Index() method? or?

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't your magical solution, it'll work.

You could do this without an `Attribute` by using `Html.Partial` and ChildActions. Granted this is a bit of work and does require a 2 more partials to maintain..

Example:

Product View where you want to display the table.

```
@Html.Action("BuildProductTable", "Products")
```

Products Controller

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    // other methods removed
    // ...

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult BuildProductTable()
    {

        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            // Return Admin ViewModel & Partial View
            // Create and populate Admin ViewModel here
            return PartialView("_AdminProductTable", ProductsAdminVM);
        } 
        // Create and populate Customer ViewModel here
        return PartialView("_CustomerProductTable", ProductsCustomerVM );
    }
}
```

Then you can create two partial view to display the tables the way you want with the columns you want using the ViewModel you passed to it.

Customer Product Table Partial View

```
@model YourProject.Web.Models.ProductsCustomerVM
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data..</td>
    <td>data..</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Admin Product Table Partial View

```
@model YourProject.Web.Models.ProductsAdminVM
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data..</td>
    <td>data..</td>
    <td>data..</td>
    <td>data..</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Doing it this way keeps your role checking logic out of your view.